# NgFor looping through array inside of object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngfor

I am pulling data from an API, and trying to render that data on the page.

**JSON structure:**

```
{page: 1, results: Array(20), total_pages: 832, total_results: 16629}
page: 1 
results: Array(20) 
0:
adult: false
backdrop_path: "/xDMIl84Qo5Tsu62c9DGWhmPI67A.jpg"
genre_ids: (3) [28, 12, 878]
id: 505642
original_language: "en"
original_title: "Black Panther: Wakanda Forever"
overview: "Queen Ramonda, Shuri, M’Baku, Okoye and the Dora Milaje fight to...
popularity: 7141.639
poster_path: "/sv1xJUazXeYqALzczSZ3O6nkH75.jpg"
release_date: "2022-11-09"
title: "Black Panther: Wakanda Forever"
video: false
vote_average: 7.5
vote_count: 2879
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

**Component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { tap } from 'rxjs';
import { MovieDataService } from '../services/movie-data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'home-card',
  templateUrl: './home-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home-card.component.css']
})
export class HomeCardComponent {

  movieData: any = {};
  constructor(private movieDataService: MovieDataService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.movieDataService.getData().subscribe((data) => {
      this.movieData = data;
      // JSON to console
      console.warn(data);
    })
  }
}
```

**Template**

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of movieData.results | keyvalue">
        Key: <b>{{item}}</b>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This successfully renders on the page, and renders the object like so:

[image]

But when trying to access the title field of an object i get the error: Property `title` does not exist on type `KeyValue<unknown, unknown>`.

This is how I'm trying to access the title field:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of movieData.results | keyvalue">
        Key: <b>{{item.title}}</b>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm sure that I am missing something very obvious, but I have done a lot of reading/research and haven't been able to solve it.

Comment: Are you sure that `item.title` is the correct property? Is it supposed to be `item.original_title` from your JSON structure?

Comment: why do you need this pipe: `keyvalue`? try without it

Comment: @SpencerLS there is an 'original_title' property and a 'title' property

Comment: What if, for the sake of testing, you tried to use any property, just not  `item.title`?  For example, `item.vote_average`, or `item.backdrop_path`? This is just so you can be sure that `item` contains these as keys. Or you can avoid that, and try `JSON.stringify(item)` right away in your loop, just to see what it is that you're working with in your loop.

Comment: If you want to loop through all properties and display all the key/value pairs for all results, you'll need two loops: One with `*ngFor="let result of movieData.results"` and one with `*ngFor="let item of result | keyvalue"`. Then you can access `item.key` and `item.value`.

Answer (score 1):

keyvalue pipe works only for objects, you just need to do something like this

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of movieData.results">
        Key: <b>{{item.title}}</b>
    </li>
</ul>
```